# Update CodeIgniter from version 1.7.2 to 2.0.0 - class CI_Controller not found

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to update my project from CI version 1.7.2 to CI v. 2.0.0 (then I will update to next versions - but first I need to deal with that).

So:

Path to my CI is:
/home/user/www/mysite. That’s all right, it’s written here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html That I should replace my system folder (except application folder) with this from v2.0.

I copied these directories from 2.0.0’s system folder (that’s core, database, fonts, helpers, language, libraries) and replaced older ones. I’ve done all other things - and after trying to launch my new version of CI - it shows

```
Fatal error: Class ‘CI_Controller’ not found in/home/user/sitesystem/application/controllers/test.php on line 3.
```

MY /system/core folder contains file Controller.php and it starts with

class CI_Controller 
- so everything should work fine - what’s going on?

Comment: Did you replace your `index.php`? The `index.php` in 1.x is different than `index.php` in 2.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in CI 2, the application folder is in the root dir, not under the system directory. And second, if you watch closely your error say:

/home/user/sitesystem/application/

and you wrote previously, that the path is:

/home/user/www/mysite

so i would check this 2 things first.

Comment: I didn't even catch the mismatching paths. This could definitely be it.